# Why Custom php install is needed to install APC

Tags: php, shell, hosting, apc

I don't know it is the right place to ask this question but still for me it is the best place to ask question so i am asking this

"My Aim is to install alternative php cache (apc) on my website (hosted by dreamhost) "

My problem is it is not installing by following the wiki http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Pecl_APC .That wiki clearly specified that i need to run a custom php install in order to install APC but whyy?? isn't there a way to install APC in existing php version .My site uses php 5.2.17. Please help me i am stuck into this from a very long time now.The dreamhost wiki is not helpful at all i need answer from someone who has installed APC on their server please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to install a custom PHP because APC is a plugin that to configure needs compiling with PHP. So I guess dream host do not want to give you access to the default installation.

Did you try installing the custom PHP?

What error have you come across?

Comment: yes you are correct i need to make a custom php install but my requirement of work does not allow that so i am doing my task in another way